# How 'is' operator is not working with input() method?

Tags: python, python-3.x

`is` operator : I know that `is` operator checks whether both the operands refer to the same object or not.

```
a = "Hello World!"
b = a

print(a == b)
print(a is b)
```

**output**

```
True
True
```

Now, I will use `input()` to get input from the user.

```
c = "Python"
d = input("Enter string : ")

print(c == d)
```

**output**

```
Enter string : Python
True
```

but if I will try to print

```
print(c is d)
```

**output**

```
False
```

I don't know why it is happening with `input()`.

If I directly assign one variable to another variable, `is` operator is working fine but if I will get same value from `input()`, `is` opeartor will be given `False`.

I want to know that, why it is not referring the same object when we use `input()`.

Comment: Why do you *think* they *should* be same object?

Comment: because if we write `a="Hello" b="Hello"` then it will refer same object. So, if we will get the value of b as "Hello" from input() then also it should be refer to the same object as per my thoughts.

Comment: That totally depends on implementation details, like string literals in code blocks being optimized to be the same object, but there's no reason to believe that they should be, and knowing when the compiler decides that isn't straightforward. Note, it is **always** the case that `a = b` will mean `a is b`, but just because two objects are *equal* does not mean they will be *identical*. Just because the compiler does optimizations underneath the hood doesn't imply it always will, and you shouldn't rely on that behavior anyway, because it is an implementation detail.

Comment: IOW you shouldn't be surprised that `print(c is d)` is False, what *should* surprise you is that `a="Hello"; b="Hello"; print(a is b)` is *true*.

Comment: In IDLE you even get different results for `x is y` depending on if you write `x = y = 999` or `x = 999` and `y = 999` on two different lines. Then switch `999` with `23` and the result will be different again. So as @juanpa.arrivillaga said: it's an implementation detail.

Comment: @Matthias to be clear, if you do `x = y = <whatever>` then `x is y` will *always be true*. Same with `x = <whatever>` then `y = x`